# How prove this inequality$4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+9a^2b^2c^2\ge 21$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, substitution, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

let $a,b,c\in R$,and such $$ab+bc+ac=3$$
show that
$$4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+9a^2b^2c^2\ge 21$$

if this equlity condition is $a,b,c$ be postive numbers,and I can use $pqr$ to prove it.

But this is $a,b,c$ are real numbers

let $a+b+c=p,ab+bc+ac=q=3,abc=r$
so
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=p^2-6$$
then
$$4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+9a^2b^2c^2=4p^2-24+9r^2$$
since $a,b,c\in R$,so I can't use this important schur inequality：
$$9r\ge 4pq-p^3,a,b,c>0$$

Comment: consider the cubic $f(x) = x^3+3x^2+3x+d$ in $xd$ plane : $$d = x^3+3x^2+3x$$ find the value of $d$ for which the roots are real

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$, $abc=w^3$ and $u^2=tv^2$.

Hence, our inequality is equivalent to $w^6\geq v^4(5v^2-4u^2)$.
Since, the inequality does not depend on substitution $a\rightarrow-a$, $b\rightarrow-b$ and $c\rightarrow-c$, we can assume $u\geq0$.
Easy to show that $(a-b)^2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2\geq0\Leftrightarrow3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6$ or

$3uv^2-2u^3-2\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^3}\leq w^3\leq3uv^2-2u^3+2\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^3}$.

For $t\geq\frac{5}{4}$ the inequality is obviously true.

But for $1\leq t\leq\frac{5}{4}$ it remains to prove that
$2\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^3}+v^2\sqrt{5v^2-4u^2)}\leq3uv^2-2u^3$
or

$u^2(3v^2-2u^2)^2\geq\left(2\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^3}+v^2\sqrt{5v^2-4u^2)}\right)^2$
or

$t(3-2t)^2\geq\left(2\sqrt{(t-1)^3}+\sqrt{5-4t}\right)^2$
or

$t-1\geq4\sqrt{(t-1)^3(5-4t)}$ or

$(t-1)^2(8t-9)^2\geq0$. Done!